# React JS: Manipulate DOM element from different (child) component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom, react-hooks

I am working on a React Project which consists of different spread components, that are used together in one place.

I have a file for routes that renders me a component (this is what I want to manipulate):

> /.../packages/frontend/src/app/modules/Calculator/CalculatorRoutes.js

```
<Col ref="example" id="calculatorRoutes" span={16}>
                    <ActineoRoute
                      path={[
                        `${url}/:snr-:personId/Reserveblatt`,
                        `${url}/:snr-:personId/Berechnungseinstellungen`,
                        `${url}/:snr-:personId/Reserveberechnung`,
                      ]}
                      component={SwitchPersonHeader}
                    />
```

I want to manipulate it inside here (a button click should change the state of show to true/false and change the class name of the element regardingly)

> /.../packages/frontend/src/app/modules/Calculator/CalculationOverview/index.js

I tried it with UseEffect, but that only runs once and not outside:

```
let DOMel;
  useEffect(() => {
    // ️ use document.getElementById()
    DOMel = document.getElementById('calculatorRoutes');
    console.log(DOMel);
    console.log(show);
    DOMel.className = show ? 'ant-col ant-col-16' : 'ant-col ant-col-24';
  }, []);
```

What do I have to do, when I want it to dynamically change this in the above component? Outside of useEffect I am not able to change it.

Answer (score 0):

I believe React Context is what you need. I think you need to share states between two different components. Context is the solution for that.

See the docs here: https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html

Then you can easily read/change the state in components that are inside Context Provider.